# Scenario: 'Profile view' vs 'Dashboard view'

Tags: profile, dashboard, visibility

I have a scenario with *n* groups. Each group has:
- a coordinator viewing all the cases managed by his group;
- the simple users viewing their own cases.

The "problem" is that there exists an *n+1*-th group with the same features but with a difference: the users of this group are able to **see all the cases**.

I have prepared Dashboards including Cases-Status, Cases-Priority, and so on. Everything works because when the specific user enters in his home he sees the Cases he is interested in.

Again, the problem is for the users of the last group. They can see all the Cases, so their Dashboards are related to all the Cases, but they are **interested to see only their Cases in their Dashboard**.

Summarizing: a group of users can see all the Cases, but in the Dashboard I want let they seeing only their Cases. Do you know a solution without work-arounds? Could the *Case teams* be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that your only option will be to create the same reports that only contain the n+1 group's cases and a Dashboard that uses those Reports, then put them in a folder that's just for the n+1 group. You could also copy the same reports into a folder for them and presumably put filters on the report to only include cases that apply to the n+1 group.

Clearly with their permissions, they're going to need to have Dashboards that are created from Reports that only contain data with their cases or else the group is going to be viewing everyone else's cases too. There's no way to make their permissions more restrictive, only to expand them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered adding a filter on owner (role / profile / name etc.) to the dashboard which any user in the n+1 group could apply? This would save you having to duplicate the reports for each separate group.

In the worst case scenario you'd have to list each member's name so that they could select it as their filter. But hopefully the members have been assigned a distinct role(s), profile(s) etc. so the list of filter options could be kept short.

Unfortunately you [can't](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Jm0aAAC) be too smart and create a formula field to use as the dashboard filter though.